# Chaining Promises in native Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to chain 3 promises together but there's some behaviour I can't figure out regarding the `resolve` and `reject` functionality. I've simplified my code in order to ask the question:

```js
function testP(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Do Work', num);
    reject(num);
  });
}

function testPromises() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      testP(1)
        .then(testP(2))
        .then(testP(3))
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
  });
};

const theTest = testPromises().then(()=>{
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("ERR", err);
});
```

And what I'm seeing in my output is:

```
Do Work 1
Do Work 2
Do Work 3
ERR 1
```

Why does the code get to `Do Work 2` and `Do Work 3` if the first promise hits `reject` immediately? My understanding was that the `then` functions wait for the promise to `resolve` or `reject` before executing.

Comment: BTW `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { smth().then(smth2).then(resolve).catch(reject); })` is antipattern. It is much better to use `return smth().then(smth2);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you do

```
.then(testP(2))
```

you **call** `testP` immediately and unconditionally, passing in 2, and then pass its return value into `.then`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

This code:

```
  testP(1)
    .then(testP(2))
    .then(testP(3))
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
```

is evaluated like this (some minor details omitted):

- Call `testP` with the value 1 and remember the resulting value as `p1`
- Call `testP` with the value 2
- Call `p1.then` with the result of that call and remember the resulting value as P2
- Call `testP` with the value 3
- Call `p2.then` with the result of that call and remember the resulting value as `p3`
- Call `p3.then` with the value `resolve` and remember the result as `p4`
- Call `p4.catch` with the value `reject`
- Call the `reject` function from the first call to `testP` with the value 1
- Call the `reject` from `testPromises` with the value 1

If you want that `testP` to wait until the first one is settled, you don't *call* it, you pass a reference to it:

```
.then(testP)
```

If you want it to have an argument baked in, use `bind`:

```
.then(testP.bind(null, 2))
```

or an inline function:

```
.then(function() {
    return testP(2);
 })
```

Example *(requires a browser with `Promise`)*:

```js
function testP(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Do Work', num);
    reject(num);
  });
}

function testPromises() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      testP(1)
        .then(testP.bind(null, 2))
        .then(testP.bind(null, 3))
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
  });
};

const theTest = testPromises().then(()=>{
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("ERR", err);
});
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that a non-function type passed to `then` is nonsense and gets just ignored (since `testP(2)` is evaluated to a `Promise`)